# How to require checkboxes be checked in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Can someone please help me figure out how to require more than one checkbox to be checked on my aspx page? I have found a few articles that show how to do this with JavaScript, but I use VB and I am not sure how to apply it.

What I would like to do is once the user clicks the submit button it will display an error if enough checkboxes have not been checked. These are not in a checkbox list but rather individual checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CustomValidator` for this purpose.

Within your ASPX page, you put it in your controls and the validator.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:Label AssociatedControlID="CheckBox1" runat="server">Check this box!</asp:Label>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
<asp:Label AssociatedControlID="CheckBox2" runat="server">And this box!</asp:Label>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="You must check all of the boxes"
    OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

After this, you can check they click *Submit* by checking the `ServerValidate` event.

```
Protected Sub CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles CustomValidator1.ServerValidate
    args.IsValid = True ' set default

    If Not CheckBox1.Checked Then
        args.IsValid = False
    End If

    If Not CheckBox2.Checked Then
        args.IsValid = False
    End If
End Sub
```

The `ServerValidateEventArgs` will allow you to specify if the user has met your criteria.

At the end of `ServerValidate` event, it will return the value set in the property `IsValid` to determine if it's valid or not.

Comment: thank you for your assistance this finally worked perfectly for me!